# C# XML serialization type of IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

I want to serialize and deserialize an object like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string title;
    [XmlArray("lista")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Parameter")]
    public List<Parameter> lista;
}

public class Parameter : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string name;
    public int val;

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("name",name);
        writer.WriteElementString("val",val.ToString());
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {           
        reader.ReadToDescendant("name");
        name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        val = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I deserialize this object, it is added only the first element of the list. Example:

Serialized:

```
<Root>
<title>title</title>
<lista>
<Parameter>
  <name>pa</name>
  <val>1</val>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
  <name>pb</name>
  <val>2</val>
</Parameter>
</lista>
</Root>
```

Deserialized:

```
<Root>
<title>title</title>
<lista>
<Parameter>
  <name>pa</name>
  <val>1</val>
</Parameter>
</lista>
</Root>
```

I've realized an [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ysk9ot) example.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a custom serializer?  The above doesn't really need one.

Comment: @TimRutter It's probably an SSCCE, better than posting a 500 line class

Comment: @Sentry True enough, but worth asking I think

Comment: I'm using IXmlSerializable because in the real code the class "Parameter" has a variable of type "System.Object"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just reading the first element you shoud add `reader.Read();` at the end of RealXml method to create a loop:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
  reader.ReadToDescendant("name");
  name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
  val = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
  reader.Read();
}
```

but you don't need to implement `IXmlSerializable` if you don't have a particular reason for it. 
you could simply use `XmlSerializer` as below:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(result))
 {
     serializer.Serialize(writer, root);  /// serialize              
 }

 using (var reader = new StringReader(result.ToString()))
 {
    var deserialized = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //// deserialize from string
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using IXmlSerializable because in the real code the class "Parameter" has a variable of type "System.Object"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a custom serializer changing Parameter class to the following solves the problem (tested in your fiddle example):

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int val {get;set;}

}
```